# Не понятние 3 точки на NavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, ios9

Добрый день, использую прозрачный NavBar,

Прописанные параметры отключения кнопки назад.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Но при первом переходе в новый контроллер, появляются вот такие три  синие точки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если перейти назад и опять, зайти в этот контролер, точки больше не появятся, подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема исчезла когда я убрал свойство

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```